# How to get dynamic RigidBody rotation/tilt on uneven platform?

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I have a rigid body with PolygonCollider2D which has some complex circular shape and I'm using uneven platform.

Im using Following code to move the object forward

```
CharacterRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (speed, CharacterRigidBody.velocity.y);
```

**Problem :** The rigid body keeps on rotating when it moves forward.

[image]

I want the character to move without rotation on asymmetrical  platform(above).But i don't want to freeze rotation because i want the character to tilt when climbing or decending platform.

My RigidBody2D config(I'm using unity 5.1.2)

[image]

Can collider do anything with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It you look at the [`Rigidbody`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) or ([`Rigidbody2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html)) in the inspector under Constraints > Freeze Rotation you will see a checkbox for each  applicable axis.  These checkboxes will stop the physics engine from applying any rotation about that axis.

[image] [image]

---

Now that we have stopped the physics engine from managing the rotation we can control it ourselves by manipulating either [`Rigidbody.rotation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html) or [`Rigidbody2D.rotation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-rotation.html).

---

A `Raycast` can be used to do a quick search for any colliders below the player.  `RaycastHit.normal` can then be examined to determine the slope of the collider.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // my test sprites were sometimes misaligned 
    const float standardRotation = 90f;

    // we want to ignore any colliders more distant than this
    const float rayDistance = 1f;

    // default angle
    float angle = standardRotation;

    // do we have any ground under us?
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, rayDistance);
    if (hit)
    {
        // what is the angle of the ground?
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(hit.normal.y, hit.normal.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + standardRotation;
    }

    // set our rotation to this angle
    _rigidbody2d.rotation = angle;
}
```

Comment: see my edited question i don't have an option to freeze different axis I'm using RIgidBody2D as i mentioned i don't want to freeze rotation.

Comment: I want  dynamic rotation(more like tilt)because I'm using asymmetrical/ uneven platform see my edited question.

Comment: Tried your code but the final angle that i get is 180degrees and my player gets locked to that rotation.

Comment: @user75648 Then it sounds like you might need a different value for `standardRotation`.

Comment: Im using -90 In standardRotation. Because my player flips up side down when 90degrees is used. But either way the rotation freezes  though.

Comment: @user75648 Hmm.. This should work (or at least it does for me).  Are your sprites large (in game units)? If so you might increase `rayLength`. If that doesn't get it working you might try debug it, using `Debug.DrawRay()` to draw both raycast and hit.normal should help you see what is going wrong.

Comment: can you please send your project to me so that i understand where is the mistake I'm doing?